# How to store file in postgres database using hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, bytea

I am new to Hibernate.
I need to store file in postgres, data type of the column is `bytea`.
I looked around on internet for a working demo of this case, however I couldn't find any.

Hibernate mapping :

```
<property name="fileData" type="binary">
   <column name="fileData" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

POJO :

```
    private byte[] fileData;
        public byte[] getFileData() {
            return fileData;
        }
        public void setFileData(byte[] fileData) {
            this.fileData = fileData;
        }
```

table :

```
    create table nmonData(id int, buildNumber int, path text, fileName text, fileData bytea);
```

Error :

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [fileData] in table [nmondata]; found [bytea (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [binary(255) (Types#VARBINARY)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at com.psl.perf.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:34)
    at com.psl.perf.DAO.NmonReportFileDaoImpl.save(NmonReportFileDaoImpl.java:15)
    at com.psl.perf.service.DataService.saveNmonCSV(DataService.java:249)
    at com.psl.perf.main.Main2.main(Main2.java:8)
Jan 22, 2016 12:26:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:5432/perf]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.psl.perf.DAO.NmonReportFileDaoImpl.save(NmonReportFileDaoImpl.java:17)
    at com.psl.perf.service.DataService.saveNmonCSV(DataService.java:249)
    at com.psl.perf.main.Main2.main(Main2.java:8)
```

can someone share working demo or link for it?

> **This worked for me**
>   commenting  `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>` in
>   hibernate config file did the trick for me, however I'm confuse now
>   about what should be the data type of column and member variable in
>   java for storing file.

Comment: bytea in PG maps to byte[] in Java. I assume you want to store the file contents and not the reference (location). Declare the object field corresponding to the column as byte[]. Convert your file to a byte[] and set it as the field value. When your save your object the file contents will be mapped to the bytea column. While reading from the database read the byte array and reconstruct the file from the byte[].

Comment: @ShireResident I did something similar, however still getting the error.
I edited the post added code snippets and error.

Comment: Can you post code of NmonReportFileDaoImpl.java?

Comment: @DavidSiro NmonReportFileDaoImpl.java is just to get a session and save the object, it does nothing else. Do you still want to see the code?

Comment: @ketu b why is this throwing a NPE? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.psl.perf.DAO.NmonReportFileDaoImpl.save(NmonReportFileDaoImpl.java:17) Also, what version of Hibernate / PG are you using?

Comment: Hibernate 5.0.6, postgres 9.4

Comment: What is causing the NullPointerException? It works for me with Hibernate 5.0.6 and the XML configuration.

Comment: I assume it is because of the validation `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>` in hibernate config.
After removing the validation property, exception is gone, and file is stored in database.

Comment: @ShireResident can you suggest on what should be the postgres datatype and corresponding type in java for `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>` this to work without any issues?

Comment: @ketu b what dialect have you set?  It is working on my side even with the validate. I suspect it might be set to <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property> for unit testing.

Comment: @ShireResident 
`<property name="hibernate.connection.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>`
could it be something due to the hibernate version i.e. 5.0.6 i'm using?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you need to store file contents into PG bytea column.

> PostgreSQL DDL

```
CREATE TABLE data_object
(
  obj_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  obj_name character(30),
  obj_file bytea,
  CONSTRAINT data_object_pkey PRIMARY KEY (obj_id)
)
```

> Java Object

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "data_object")
public class DataObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "obj_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "obj_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "obj_file")
    private byte[] file;

    // getters, setters, hasCode, equals, toString
```

> Driver Code

```
byte[] data = new byte[FILE_SIZE];
// read file contents into data
DataObject obj = new DataObject();
obj.setFile(data);
// save obj using your hibernate session
```

I am using Hibernate 4.3.7 and PG 9.4.1